# Having trouble with random number in Python

Tags: python, list

Heres a snippet of my code. It keeps saying the user is incorrect when they are not. The answer to each question is in the same order within the list.

## Question Bank

```
        questions = ["45 - 20","32 - 12","54 + 41"]

        # Answer Bank
        answers = ["25","20","95"]


        while qleft != 0:


            # Get random question
            qnumber = randint(0,2)
            currentquestion = questions[qnumber]
            currentanswer = answers[qnumber]

            # Question
            userchoice = int(input("What does {} equal? ".format(currentquestion)))

            # Check Answer
            if userchoice != currentanswer:
                print("Incorrect")
                qleft -= 1
            elif userchoice == currentanswer:
                print("Correct")
                qleft -= 1

            else:
                print("That's not a valid answer")
```

Comment: Looks like a classic case of `integer != string` to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's answer, `userchoice`, is an integer, but the actual answer, `currentanswer` is a string. It will work if you just leave the input as a string:

```
    questions = ["45 - 20","32 - 12","54 + 41"]

    # Answer Bank
    answers = ["25","20","95"]


    while qleft != 0:


        # Get random question
        qnumber = randint(0,2)
        currentquestion = questions[qnumber]
        currentanswer = answers[qnumber]

        # Question
        userchoice = input("What does {} equal? ".format(currentquestion))

        # Check Answer
        if userchoice != currentanswer:
            print("Incorrect")
            qleft -= 1
        elif userchoice == currentanswer:
            print("Correct")
            qleft -= 1

        else:
            print("That's not a valid answer")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing an `int` input with a `str` answer, which are never equal.

If you want to deal with ints, change

```
answers = ["25","20","95"]
```

to

```
answers = [25,20,95]
```

and it'll work.

Alternatively, do not convert the result of `input()` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference:

```
    import random as r

    questions = ["45 - 20","32 - 12","54 + 41"]

    # Answer Bank
    answers = [25,20,95]

    qleft = 3

    while qleft != 0:


        # Get random question
        qnumber = r.randint(0,2)
        currentquestion = questions[qnumber]
        currentanswer = answers[qnumber]

        # Question
        userchoice = int(input("What does {} equal? ".format(currentquestion)))

        # Check Answer
        if userchoice != currentanswer:
            print("Incorrect")
            qleft -= 1
        elif userchoice == currentanswer:
            print("Correct")
            qleft -= 1

        else:
            print("That's not a valid answer")
```

notice that "25" != 25

Answer (score 0):

Since you are converting the user's answers to int, the correct answers also nee to be int.  Otherwise, you are comparing strings to int and it will never be equal.

```
answers = [25, 20, 95]
```